# group cohomology of abelianization

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Is it true that, for a finite or compact group $G$,
$$H^3(G,\mathbb{Z})=H^3(G/[G,G],\mathbb{Z})\times H^3([G,G],\mathbb{Z})~?$$
It is clearly true for abelian and perfect $G$. I have checked a few other examples, and it has held.

Comment: What do you mean by "="? Isomorphism as abelian groups?

Comment: This really seems very unlikely. I don't know much about third cohomology groups, but I found a counterexample using a computer calculation in Magma. I took $G$ to be the direct product of two copies of the dihedral group of order $8$. Then $H^3(G,Z)$, $H^3([G,G],Z)$ and $H^3(G/[G,G],Z)$ are elementary abelian of order $2^6$, $2$, and $2^6$, respectively.

Comment: @DerekHolt A theoretical reason why taking direct products will often destroy this property: If the isomorphism holds for finite groups $G$ and $H$, then calculating $H^3$ with the Kunneth formula shows that the isomorphism holds for $G\times H$ iff $\text{Tor}(H^2(G),H^2(H))\cong \text{Tor}(H^2(G/[G,G]),H^2(G/[G,G]))\oplus\text{Tor}(H^2([G,G]),H^2([G,G]))$, which fails in your example of $G=H=D_8$ because $H^2(G)\cong C_2\times C_2\cong H^2(G/[G,G])$, but $H^2([G,G])\cong C_2$. I think $S_3\times S_3$ should be another counterexample.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Yes you are right, with $G=S_3$, $H^3(G,Z)$, $H^3([G,G],Z)$ and $H^3(Q,Z)$ have order $2$, $3$, and $2$.

Comment: By the way, in my previous comment, five of my $G$s should be $H$s. :-(

Comment: Thank you for the nice family of counter examples. I wonder whether it is still possible that in general $H^3(G,Z)$ splits as a product either of $H^3(G/[G,G],Z)$ and something or of $H^3([G,G],Z)$ and something.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a short exact sequence of groups $1 \to N \to G \to G/N \to 1$ leads to a spectral sequence of group cohomology, with 
$$ E_2^{pq} = H^p(G/N, H^q(N, A)) \implies H^{p+q}(G,A).$$
This is known as the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence.
This tells us roughly that $H^3(G)$ will be determined by the cohomologies in pairs of degrees which add to $3$, modulo relations arising from total degrees $2$ and $4$.

Note here that $H^q(N,A)$ is a $G/N$-module, and may be nontrivial even if $A$ is a trivial $G$-module. So, this cohomology depends on the way $N$ and $G/N$ interact in $G$.

Comment: Thanks. There are relations on the $E_2^{pq}$ coming from differentials. Taking these into account, one eventually converges to $E_\infty^{pq}$. Finally, there is an extension problem to find $H^n$ from $E_\infty^{p,n-p}$. Do you know whether either the first or the last term is guaranteed to survive the relations and then split off? ie... do we have either $H^n(G,A)=H^n(N,A)\times\text{(something)}$ or $H^n(G,A)=H^n(G/N,A)\times\text{(something)}$? (I know something similar happens for the AHSS $H^p(X,h^q(\text{pt}))$ for generalized cohomology: $h(X)=h(\text{pt})\times\tilde h(X)$).